# How to switch views randomly in storyboard using code

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

I was wondering if possible to switch views randomly in storyboard. If it is possible could you please show me how. At the moment I have have the code for a random cycle but, I do not have the code for switching views. The current code is listed below.

```
-(IBAction)RandomButton:(id)sender {

    int randomviews = rand() % 2;
    switch (randomviews) {
        case 0:

            //// Where the code for switching views

            break;
        case 1:

            //// Another spot for switching views

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean switch view CONTROLLERS (VCs), not views.

If you want to invoke a VC using a segue, you could use performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

If you want to invoke a VC using a push onto a navigation controller, or push it modally, you could load the VC using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: and then invoke the resulting view controller however you want.

In your code above, you could have an array of NSStrings containing segue or VC identifiers, and use your randomViews value as an index into that array. Then just use the string at that index as your identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter your **views** randomly, then what you do is that you have a reference the view the is being active at the moment (( i.e: `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *currentlyActiveView;` )), and you alter that view as the following:

```
-(IBAction)RandomButton:(id)sender {

    int randomviews = rand() % 2;
    switch (randomviews) {
        case 0:

            //// Where the code for switching views
            [self.currentlyActiveView removeFromSuperview];
            self.currentlyActiveView = [something loadSomeView:randomviews];
            [self.view addSubview:self.currentlyActiveView];
            //// ***** and this way you only have to write your code once, regardless of your current switch case ;)
            break;
        case 1:

            //// Another spot for switching views

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

hope it helps =)